# '"lilypond"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: luatex, texlive, windows, lilypond, command-line

I am interested in using *ly*LuaTeX. I am used to Overleaf, but Overleaf seems incompatible with *ly*LuaTeX, so I have downloaded TeX Live and Texmaker. Page 5 of the *ly*LuaTeX documentation (https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/support/lyluatex/lyluatex.pdf#page=5) says

> *ly*LuaTEX requires that LuaLATEX is started with the --shell-escape command line option[.]

I have opened the command line, gone to the relevant directory, typed `lualatex --shell-escape MYFILENAME.tex`, and pressed Enter.

Among other messages the following appeared:

**'"lilypond"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

**(lyluatex)      Compiling score tmp-ly/604bac4d10faf7e5a1619a45fc23ffb7 with LilyPond executable 'lilypond'.**

**c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109:**

**Module lyluatex Error: LilyPond could not be started.**

**(lyluatex)             Please check that LuaLaTeX is started with the**

**(lyluatex)             --shell-escape option, and that 'program'**

**(lyluatex)             points to a valid LilyPond executable.**

**(lyluatex)             on input line 23**

*(For reference, input line 23, if it refers to the code I wrote in Texmaker, reads `\end{lilypond}`.)*

I wasn't sure what to expect, as I'm not used to using the command line yet. But when I try to recompile my document in Texmaker, *ly*LuaTeX is still not working (surprise, surprise).

I believe that I have properly attempted to start LuaLaTeX with the `--shell-escape` option. Therefore, I suspect that the problem is that the 'program' option is not pointing to a valid LilyPond executable. (In fact, I have not even called the 'program' option.) **How do I do so? And how do I make it point to a valid LilyPond executable? Does my diagnosis seem correct?**

Some further information:

Page 23 of the *ly*LuaTeX documentation (https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/support/lyluatex/lyluatex.pdf#page=23) says

> By default lyLuaTEX will invoke LilyPond through the lilypond command, which will work in
> many situations for default installations. However, in order to accomodate [sic] specific installations (Windows?) or to use specific versions of LilyPond the command to be used can be specified with the program (*lilypond*) option.

**I am using Windows.** I am guessing that the parenthetical "(Windows?)" seems to me to be the documentation authors saying, Windows users may have trouble using *ly*LuaTeX unless they use the program option to point to a valid LilyPond executable.

**EDIT:** I am attempting to manually add the Lilypond executable file to the Windows PATH environmental variable. I have gotten here (see picture):

[image]

but I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: have you installed lilypond? it's a separate program not part of tex distributions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I have installed it.

Comment: What happens if you open a command-line shell and type `lilypond --version`?

Comment: You may need to find the Lilypond executable file and add it to the Windows PATH environmental variable manually.  (https://superuser.com/questions/494538/how-do-i-open-a-program-via-the-command-prompt-in-windows-8 for example)

Comment: @musarithmia In the command line, I went to lilypond-2.24.1 > bin, which is the folder the Lilypond application lives in, for me. At this point I entered `lilypond --version`. Among other things, this appeared: `Suggestion [3,General]: The command lilypond was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\lilypond". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.` Therefore, I tried entering simply `.\lilypond`.  (See forthcoming comment.)

Comment: @musarithmia Entering simply `.\lilypond` returned the following message: "GNU LilyPond 2.24.1 (running Guile 2.2) Usage: lilypond [OPTION]... FILE... Typeset music and/or produce MIDI from FILE. LilyPond produces beautiful music notation. For more information, see https://lilypond.org". This was followed by a list of ''Options," including "-I, --include=DIR                append DIR to search path" and "-v, --version                    show version number and exit". Should I follow up somehow? Meanwhile I will try figuring out the method proposed in your second comment.

Comment: @musarithmia I am attempting to manually add the Lilypond executable file to the Windows PATH environmental variable. I have edited my question to reflect this. Do you know how to proceed from where I am?

Comment: Okay, so you found the executable location and were able to run it from the command line with `.\lilypond` . You got the standard version/help text that lilypond gives when run without any arguments (that is, with no file to process). That's one piece working correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147088/discussion-between-musarithmia-and-noah-j).